# Questions with new activity on deleted answers shouldn't be bumped to users with <10k rep

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, bump, last-activity

When checking the home page ('Active' tab), I keep seeing questions with new activities on deleted answers (new answer, edit, etc). The only problem is I don't have [the privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to view those activities. So, why bring them to my attention?

Example: <sup>(click on the screenshot for the link)</sup>

[image: Question with new activity on deleted answer]

Note that I'm not talking about a question that has just been deleted and is removed from the view when the page is refreshed. The question itself isn't deleted; only the answer with the new activity is. Those questions remain visible on the home page with a link to the new activity.

**Can you please not bump those questions to users with <10k rep?** I keep clicking on the link just to realize that it's a deleted answer that I can't view.

**P.S.** I'm not sure if this happens with activities on answers that are *already deleted* <sup>(can someone confirm?)</sup> or if it's just with answers that are deleted after the new activity (and the bump). If it's the latter, we obviously can't prevent the initial bump but I would still expect it to be removed from the view once the page is refreshed.

Comment: There are a few old requests around Meta requesting that the bump be revoked for a post that geta deleted. But it is effectively impossible to have it bump for only a subset of users. There is only one LastModifiedDate. It is the same for everyone.

Comment: @animuson How are deleted posts removed from the view once the page is refreshed then? And can't the same be done when the _answer_ is deleted? The view already contains a link to the deleted post, so I would imagine it should be possible to check the state of that particular answer and then decide whether or not to include its parent post. I obviously can be wrong though.

Comment: Because it is done for everyone. The questions lists do not include deleted questions, even for those who can view them. And it is not that easy as you make it sound. You are ignoring that there must be a LastModifiedDate in order for it to appear in the list, and calculating that on the fly because "the post associated with the most recent bump is deleted" is prohibitively expensive.

Comment: _"The questions lists do not include deleted posts, even for those who can view them"_ Hmm, yeah I guess I didn't think about that. So, [status-by-design] then? It's just really annoying because I don't know the answer is deleted until I go looking for it :-D