# Can we have a "toast" notification when visiting a direct link to a deleted answer/comment?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

#### Background:

Because users with <10k reputation cannot see deleted posts, visiting a link to a deleted answer, silently opens the parent question without a *clear* indication that the linked answer has been deleted. This can be very confusing to users who aren't familiar with the system. It makes them waste their time scrolling up and down trying to find what they visited for.

I used to get very frustrated because of this and it still annoys me sometimes even though I'm fully aware of how this works. But even those who are familiar with the system *can* get confused for a second sometimes (e.g., "Wait, did I click the wrong link?", etc.)

#### Proposal:

So, I propose showing a "toast" notification indicating that the answer has been deleted. This shouldn't affect the current workflow as the link will take the user to the question as usual; the notification is to be displayed for just a couple of seconds, and everything else remains the same. Something like the following:

[image: A "toast" notification with a text that says: "The answer that you're trying to access has been deleted."]

Or anything to that effect. Maybe "resource" should be used instead of "answer" to be more generic. I don't care about the wording of the message as long as it reflects the meaning. It also doesn't have to use this danger/error styling. A `-warning` or even `-info` class would be fine too.

#### Bonus:

- It will be great if this works with links to deleted **comments** as well.
- It will also be great if it works with `?lastactivity` links. See [my other related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363670/348196) for more info.

Comment: Are you in for using a userscript? https://stackapps.com/q/7376/18722

Comment: @rene Sure thing; Thanks a lot. [Aaaand done!](https://i.imgur.com/iJmWr0A.png) Hopefully, this will be implemented by SE at some point. Although I wouldn't really count on it as none of my other 10 [feature-request] posts received [status-anything] so far.

Comment: Nice idea. I've [filed a separate feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366378/add-a-toast-notification-when-an-anonymous-user-follows-a-link-to-an-unanswered) for unanswered duplicates for anonymous users, as that's another silent redirect.

Comment: Previous FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251026/241919, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230696/241919, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88589/241919

Comment: Yes, agreed. It is one of those violations of the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: An alternative is something similar to redirects at Wikipedia (discreetly at the top of the page *("Redirected from XXX)"*). [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) (for *"Terabyte"*).